# Looping XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I've read various things that I've followed but I can't seem to get this working. I'm returning XML from the eBay Trading API, which is working, but I can't get some nodes to echo out... (i'm newish to php / xml)

Here's a sample of the XML (stripped out as it contains order data):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2016-01-28T10:48:19.262Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>949</Version>
  <Build>E949_INTL_APIXO_17770994_R1</Build>
  <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>3</TotalNumberOfEntries>
  </PaginationResult>
  <HasMoreOrders>false</HasMoreOrders>
  <OrderArray>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>400930822745-519268006027</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <AmountPaid currencyID="GBP">213.0</AmountPaid>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>191593173254-1228482367009</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <AmountPaid currencyID="GBP">289.0</AmountPaid>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>400930822765-514681551027</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <AmountPaid currencyID="GBP">238.0</AmountPaid>
    </Order>
  </OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>​
```

Here's the PHP i'm using:

```
$responseDoc = new DomDocument();
$responseDoc->loadXML($responseXml);


$ackNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Ack');
$paginationCategoryNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('PaginationResult');
$totalNode = $paginationCategoryNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('TotalNumberOfEntries');

$orders = [];
foreach ($responseDoc->OrderArray->Order as $order) {
    $orders[] = $order->toArray();
}

echo 'Order Ack: ', $ackNode->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo '<br />Sales Quantity: ', $totalNode->item(0)->nodeValue;

print_r(array_values($orders));


/*  also tried this also but didn't work:

foreach ($responseDoc->Order as $Order) {
    echo '<br />' . $Order->OrderStatus;
}
*/
```

I know the API call is working as I can echo out the Ack:Success, and TotalNumberOfEntries:3  but not sure how to get at the Order -> OrderID, or order -> AmountPaid.

I want to loop each order to get the values for each...

Many thanks!

Comment: You're using [DomDocument](http://docs.php.net/domdocument), i.e. the [DOM](http://docs.php.net/dom) extension for php. Real question, so we know from which angle this question comes from: Why do you think you can do `$doc->element->element` and `$node->toArray()`? Is it some kind of tutorial? Or from the documentation of another library/extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correct your code in this way:

```
foreach ($responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Order') as $order) {
    echo 'Order ID: ' . $order->getElementsByTagName('OrderID')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo '<br />Order Status: ' . $order->getElementsByTagName('OrderStatus')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo '<br />Amount Paid: ' . $order->getElementsByTagName('AmountPaid')->item(0)->nodeValue . ' ' . $order->getElementsByTagName('AmountPaid')->item(0)->getAttribute('currencyID');
}
```

That if you want print the data.

Instead, if you want capture data in an array:

```
$orders = [];
foreach ($responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Order') as $order) {
    $row = array();
    $row['id'] = $order->getElementsByTagName('OrderID')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $row['status'] = $order->getElementsByTagName('OrderStatus')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $row['amount'] = $order->getElementsByTagName('AmountPaid')->item(0)->nodeValue . ' ' . $order->getElementsByTagName('AmountPaid')->item(0)->getAttribute('currencyID');
    $orders[] = $row;
}
print_r( $orders );
```

<kbd>**[sandbox demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/06a28)**</kbd>

#### Annotations:

Because `` nodes are univocals in this context, I use

```
$responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Order')
```

but you can use also

```
$responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('OrderArray')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('Order')
```

or

```
$responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('OrderArray')->item(0)->childNodes
```

Comment: This worked a treat thanks!  I'm a javascript developer and only 'getting into'  php a bit now.. so its all a bit new...     thanks a bunch i was going round in circles!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that the same way, you are accessing `Ack` or `TotalNumberOfEntries`.

To get list of `Order` nodes, you can do this:

```
$orderList = $responseDoc
               ->getElementsByTagName('OrderArray')->item(0)
               ->getElementsByTagName('Order');
```

Then you can iterate it, but inside your loop you are still dealing with `DOMElement` objects so you can't use it like simple object.

So in order to get for example OrderStatus value, instead of

```
$order->OrderStatus
```

You have to do:

```
$order->getElementsByTagName('OrderStatus')->item(0)->textContent;
```

Also please keep in mind that there's no such function like `DOMElement::toArray()`, therefore you should access every child node separately in your loop, to create `$orders` array.

Final loop could look like this:

```
$orders = [];
foreach ($orderList as $order) {    
    $orders[] = array(
        'OrderID' => $order->getElementsByTagName('OrderID')->item(0)->textContent,
        'OrderStatus' => $order->getElementsByTagName('OrderStatus')->item(0)->textContent,
        'AmountPaid' => $order->getElementsByTagName('AmountPaid')->item(0)->textContent.
        'AmountPaidCurrency' => $order->getElementsByTagName('AmountPaid')->item(0)->getAttribute('currencyID'),
    );
}
```

Please also note that I had to separately get `currencyID` attribute of `AmountPaid`. That's one of reasons why you can't simply convert HTML to array.

Comment: And then there would still be that mysterious `->toArray()` call. It's _possible_ using [DOMDocument::registerNodeClass](http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.registernodeclass.php), but there's nothing in the code that suggests something like that.

Comment: Did I use `toArray` anywhere here?

Comment: So how it relates to my answer?

Comment: thanks for the help... i couldnt get this bit working, though it was probably right and the way i've done the rest of it maybe was a little awkward...

Answer (score -1):

This is probably wrong:

```
foreach ($responseDoc->OrderArray->Order as $order) {
                                  ^^^^^^
```

You want to loop on the `Order` component, but since there's MULTIPLE of those `<order>` tags, you need to loop on its parent container, e.g. the `<OrderArray>`

```
foreach ($responseDoc->OrderArray as $order) {
                                 ^---note the difference
```

Comment: You can't access child nodes like that at all. This is basically because they may not be unique.

Comment: `foreach ($responseDoc->OrderArray->Order as $order)` would be working if SimpleXML was used.